# LaTeX not working?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

Well, that's it. MathJax doesn't appear to be working.

Maybe it hasn't been put in place yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as obsolete.

Answer (score 14):

If you wish to see LaTeX support please upvote this question.  We will revisit this in a few days.

Comment: done [ ](http://emp.ty "$\LaTeX me$")

Comment: There was enough support - MathJax is now enabled

Comment: Thank you! :-).

Comment: I love you, Geoff <3

Comment: Really, I'd $ \, \large { \bf{LOVE} } \, $ to see and use LaTeX here also!... :)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, no LaTeX support/MathJax here either, it seems. Hopefully the implementation will be copied over from math.se soon, it will definitely be needed!

Comment: I hope so! There are some questions which need to be explained with some math and lacking LaTeX support restrains users of giving a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but do we have an explanation of how to use LaTeX on this site somehwere? I couldn't seem to figure it out until now.

Comment: For now, see [the FAQ for math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117). I have [proposed a unified help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388) for MathJax/LaTeX for all SE sites having it but so far there's no response.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the correct dollar notation as a first guess, but was fooled by the fact that preview only updates once you've left the edit field and gone back into it. Hope this improves a little, or at least gets an explanation.